# How to sum the value of the collection of neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to sum each value of the collection of the neo4j can anybody can tell me the cypher for this I have three collections already

```
MEASURES1,MEASURES2,MEASURES3
```

See the Image attach below to view the problem very clearly:

[image: Image for this question see this to get a more clear idea about the question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [reduce()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function to achieve your goal. Take a look:

```
WITH [14,1] AS MEASURES1, [] AS MEASURES2, [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1] AS MEASURES3

WITH reduce(acc1 = 0, v1 in MEASURES1 | acc1 + v1) AS MEASURES1,
     reduce(acc2 = 0, v2 in MEASURES2 | acc2 + v2) AS MEASURES2,
     reduce(acc3 = 0, v3 in MEASURES3 | acc3 + v3) AS MEASURES3
RETURN MEASURES1, MEASURES2, MEASURES3
```

The result of above query:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| MEASURES1 | MEASURES2 | MEASURES3 |
+-----------------------------------+
| 15        | 0         | 13        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

**I got my Answer:**

```
RETURN 
reduce(s = 0, x IN MEASURES1 | s + x) AS MEASURES1,
reduce(s = 0, x IN MEASURES2 | s + x) AS MEASURES2,
reduce(s = 0, x IN MEASURES3 | s + x) AS MEASURES3
```

The **reduce()** function will work as we required :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions), you can use helper functions that operate on collections, including `apoc.coll.sum()` which does exactly what you need:

```
...
RETURN apoc.coll.sum(MEASURES1) as m1Sum, apoc.coll.sum(MEASURES2) as m2Sum, apoc.coll.sum(MEASURES3) as m3Sum
```

Comment: Thank you very much @inverse Falcon sir for your reply

Comment: This is valid if we have access to APOC Procedure